# Stuck in recursive query with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, subquery

```
INSERT INTO complaintstatus(complaintid,currentstatus,reason,photo,datetime,open_reopen_status,actiontaken,parent_id)
select complaint_id,status,(CASE WHEN (rejectionreason IS NULL OR rejectionreason = '') THEN reopen_reason ELSE rejectionreason END),photo_name,server_time,completion_date,reopen,actiontaken,parent_complaint_id
from complaint_details_v2 
where status !=0 
order by parent_complaint_id
```

I want to add data as per the status fetch by select query if status
 =3 then insert into complaintstatus with date selected as server_time and insert into only one record but if status is 5 then insert
 multiple insertion on behalf of completion ans server_time because
 same data is repeated only status, reopen, server_time and
 completion_date is vary according to the status.

```
select complaint_id,status,
       (CASE WHEN (rejectionreason IS NULL OR > rejectionreason = '') 
               THEN reopen_reason ELSE rejectionreason
        END),
        photo_name,
        (CASE WHEN (status='3') THEN server_time 
              ELSE completion_date 
         END),
         reopen,
         actiontaken,
         parent_complaint_id 
from
complaint_details_v2 
where status !=0 
order by parent_complaint_id
```

output of this query:

```html
ComplaintId Status rejectionreason    Photoname server_time completiondate reopen actiontaken parent_complaint_id
194          3      sitce picture      abc.jpg    2017-09-15                   0                109
                    is not available
195          5                          xyz.jpg   2017-09-15 2017-09-15        0                 195
                                                  08:22:44    00:00:00
214          5                          asd.jpg   2017-09-19                   1   repair done   214
                                                  11:23:11
1599         5                          abc.jpg   2017-09-25 2017-10-18        0   complete      214
```

[image]

In the `complaintstatus` table I have to insert data as per the
 above 0utput on the basis of status and reopen data and select
 servertime and completion date as per the status

```html
 Status rejectionreason    Photoname datetime      reopen actiontaken parent_complaint_id
  3     site picture       xyz.jpg    2017-09-15     0                 194
        are not available             07:59:59.582                  
  5                        abc.jpg    2017=09-15     0     repair done  195
                                      08:22:44.247
  5                        asd.jpg    2017-09-19     0     repairdone   214
                                      11:23:11.274
  0                                   2017-09-25     0                  214
                                      18:23:07.181
  5                        asd.jpg    2017-10-18     0     complete     214
```

[image]

Comment: is this mysql or postgresql? They are different products. Please only tag the database engine you are actually referring to, thanks.

Comment: postgresql i needed

Comment: Please provide your sample data as formatted text and not as screenshot.

Comment: @Tony94: see the edited question, i  tried to add sample data.Please help me out